# How to get line->next in Python

Tags: python, iteration

I'm iterating through a file of employee records line-by-line and trying to insert a new line (record of a shift worked) into the file at the end of an employee's record, which is marked by a "?".

So basically my file looks like this:

> Staff ##### !
>  Joe Smith
>  Employee
>  first shift
>  second shift
>  ?
>  !
>  Jane Smith
>  Occassional volunteer
>
> first shift
>  second shift
>  third shift
>  ?
>  @

...and I want to, say, add a 'fourth shift' to Jane Smith's record.  I'd like to do this by iterating through a working copy of the file, finding jane's record (using a flag) and then when the current line's successor (line->next ??) is "?" I know my current line is the last recorded shift by Jane.  I can then write in the 'fourth shift' line before continuing to copy the remainder of the old file into my new one.

When I'm iterating through all these lines, how do I read the *following* line (to check for a "?") without actually skipping ahead to it?

Comment: Denis: "RTFM" doesn't really help as much as you think it does.  If you want to be terse and unhelpful with novices while remaining nebulous (i.e. "go read this phone-book sized document for an answer to your very specific problem"), then please don't answer my questions.  People already know how to spend a week pouring over software documentation without learning what they need to know.

Comment: Stack Overflow gets a ton of overly trivial questions that could have been answered by simply checking the documentation, and people are getting increasingly tired of them. However you are right, there are cases were you might already have searched the documentation for hours and just couldn't find the answer. Next time, just say so ;) Tell us what and where you've search, give us at least a hint that you've tried to solve your own problem. As you get more familiar with Stack Overflow you'll hopefully realize why we sometimes have to be vigilant.

Comment: Oh, and that youtube link was pointless, please keep your questions concise in the future, without any unnecessary fluff.

Answer (score 1):

Anyways, you basically can't just insert a line in the middle of a file. Instead, you should overwrite the old file with a new file that contains the new line. So the solution goes something like this:

1. Open the file for reading.
2. Save the file's contents, preferably line by line to make it easier to insert at a specific line.
3. Insert your new line into the saved contents.
4. Re-open the file, this time in write mode, and overwrite its contents with the saved modified contents.

So, for your example, and using your flag idea to find the insert point, you would do something like this:

```
#Step 1
with open('testFile', 'r') as f:
    #Step 2
    contentList = f.readlines()

#Step 3
isJane = False # <-- flag
i = 0
insertIndex = None # used to avoid changing the list while looping over it
for line in contentList:
    if 'jane' in line.lower():
        isJane = True
    if isJane and line.strip() == '?':
        insertIndex = i
    i += 1
contentList.insert(insertIndex, 'fourth shift\n')

#Step 4
with open('testFile', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(contentList)
```

There are shorter ways of doing this, but this is probably the most straightforward.

Comment: Good call on the edit. Relevant meta question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145681/is-it-bad-etiquette-to-answer-a-question-that-already-has-lots-of-downvotes